# How to replace newlines with tab characters?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk

I have pattern like below

```
hi
hello
hallo
greetings
salutations
no more hello for you
```

I am trying to replace all newlines with tab using the following command

```
sed -e "s_/\n_/\t_g"
```

but it's not working.

Could anybody please help? I'm looking for a solution in sed/awk.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

not sure about output you want

```
# awk -vRS="\n" -vORS="\t" '1' file
hi      hello   hallo   greetings       salutations     no more hello for you
```

Answer (score 52):

`tr` is better here, I think:

```
tr "\n" "\t" < newlines
```

As Nifle suggested in a comment, `newlines` here is the name of the file holding the original text.

Because `sed` is so line-oriented, it's more complicated to use in a case like this.

Comment: @Nifle: Also no `cat` here, but who's counting? :)

Comment: @Tele I'm a cat overuser, I admit that.

Comment: is there a way to do this in sed itself?

Comment: -1 as i already know that we can do it with tr but i need how to do it in sed

Comment: @John: someone may be able to tell you how to do it in `sed`, but given that `sed` is so line-oriented, that's a bit like hammering in a screw.

Answer (score 11):

```
sed '$!{:a;N;s/\n/\t/;ta}' file
```

Comment: could you please also explain about the command you are using?

Comment: if its not the last line , get the next line join with pattern space, substitute the newline and then branch to :a and do the same for every line

Comment: +1! This worked for me, even when the file only had one line then a new, empty line. Most of the other solutions negatively surprised me. I don't like such surprises.

Comment: doesn't work i `csh`

Answer (score 7):

```
paste -s
```

-s          Concatenate all of the lines of each separate input file in
                 command line order.  The newline character of every line
                 except the last line in each input file is replaced with the
                 tab character, unless otherwise specified by the -d option.

Answer (score 6):

You can't replace newlines on a line-by-line basis with `sed`. You have to accumulate lines and replace the newlines *between* them.

```
text abc\n    <- can't replace this one

text abc\ntext def\n    <- you can replace the one after "abc" but not the one at the end
```

This `sed` script accumulates all the lines and eliminates all the newlines but the last:

```
sed -n '1{x;d};${H;x;s/\n/\t/g;p};{H}'
```

By the way, your `sed` script `sed -e "s_/\n_/\t_g"` is trying to say "replace all slashes followed by newlines with slashes followed by tabs". The underscores are taking on the role of delimiters for the `s` command so that slashes can be more easily used as characters for searching and replacing.

Answer (score 0):

Also if using Variables, Here Strings or Here Documents:

```bash
tr "\n" "\t" <<< "a
b
c
d
"
```

```bash
paste -s <<EOF
a
b
c
d
EOF
```

Answer (score -2):

You are almost there with your sed script, you'd just need to change it to:

```
sed -e "s/\n/\t/g"
```

The `\` is enough for escape, you don't need to add `_`
And you need to add the `/` before `g` at the end to let sed know that this is the last part of the script.