# replace new lines with commas in shell

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, sed, awk

I want to replace new lines in text with coma or space but do not change the last new line.

I know of this question: [How to replace newlines with tab characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1617724/497756) - but it does produce an tab on end instead of new line.

So far I have come with:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf","} {printf $1} END{printf"\n"}'
```

Is there an easier way to do this? This is not an assignment, I am just curious want to level up my scripting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
paste -s -d, file
```

or

```
paste -s -d" " file
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do a job:

```
echo  ${$(tr '\n' ',' < file)%?}
```

or perhaps using sed:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n/,/g' file
```

Comment: I was searching for something less magical, those both require quite good knowledge of `bash`/`tr` or `sed` respectively

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` is not quite as simple as `paste`, but it does generalize to more cases:

```
perl -0pe 's/\n(?!$)/,/g' filename  # comma
perl -0pe 's/\n(?!$)/ /g' filename  # space
```

The `(?!$)` is a lookahead assertion that means "not at the end", so the last newline is left alone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed command to remove the end ","

```
 # sed -i 's/,$//g' endmodify.txt

 # cat endmodify.txt
 root
 bin
 daemon
 adm
 lp
 sync
 games
 gopher
```

Thanks.

Comment: as you can see the result is coma at the last line, the question was how to avoid it

Comment: Hi mpapis: sorry for the update: then we can use, # sed -i 's/,$//g' endmodify.txt  .